# Interpretation of chained Booleans

Tags: python

I was answering another question and came across something similar to this:

```
n = 1
l = [1, 2, 3]

print(n in l is True)
# False

# same for:
print(n in l == True)
# False
```

When I looked at it, I intuitively knew what was wrong, but after trying to explain the issue I noticed I don't actually understand the problem here.

It might be a silly question, but why does this return `False`?

Edit: I know the `is True` is not required and I could solve it by using brackets around `n in l`

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

Comment: @Sujay was my first idea as well, but `==` will also return False

Comment: Because it's interpreted as `(n in l) and (l == True)` -> `True and False` -> `False`.

Comment: but `l` in non-empty list, it should be interpreted as `True`. No?

Comment: [Be careful with chained operations](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfPython#-be-careful-with-chained-operations)

Comment: @Prophet it's _truthy_, but that's not the same as being equal to `True`.

Comment: What you think happens: `(n in l) is True`. What happens: `(n in l) and (l is True)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe and @timgeb ahh! so its basically a chain of `and` operations between each pair. What confused me was that if you unpack the chain `l` is used twice, once with `n` and once with `is True`. Thank you very much for the explaination.